# Increasing root space in AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am setting up a g3.16xlarge instance at AWS for a deep learning project.  After installing cuda libraries, I am facing space shortage issue.  The `df -h` output the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            241G     0  241G   0% /dev
tmpfs            49G  8.8M   49G   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.4G  376M  96% /
tmpfs           241G     0  241G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           241G     0  241G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/495
/dev/loop1       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5328
tmpfs            49G     0   49G   0% /run/user/1000
```

While my root `/dev/xvda1` is full, I have `241G in`udev`partition.  Can I allot that space to`/dev/xvda1`.  When I checked for solutions, all I am getting to see is to increase the size of`EBS Volume` online, which I don't want to do, as I am already spending a huge fee for this machine.  Even before I could complete the setup I stumbled upon this issue.

I have chosen a Ubuntu 16.04 AMI.  However, this doesn't happen if I choose Ubuntu 16.04 AMI that is pre-configured for deep learning.

Comment: [This might help you](https://askubuntu.com/q/994357/186548)

Comment: @MarcoA. How disappointing....Thank you however for pointing me to the right link.